# Convert string to num with cellfun

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the next problem:

```
A=[2014;20;2012;32155];
```

Then I want to convert `A` in a cell array with string characters, with the character `A` prepended to each of the strings.  In other words, I wish to do this if I were to create a manual cell array:

```
A={'A2014';'A20';'A2012';'A32155'};
```

Can anybody make this without using a loop? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `num2cell(A)`? For the second option, you can't use `cellfun` because `A` is not a cell array. Use `arrayfun(@num2str,A,'uniformoutput',false)`

Comment: Try `num2str(A)`. Or second option in my first comment

Comment: to be exact, that should be: `strtrim(cellstr(num2str(A)))` (to get a cell array of strings)

Comment: @lisandrojim: If you want to use the `cellfun` option, you would have to provide a handler to `num2str`.  i.e., you would do this: `A = cellfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false);`.  You would have to set the `UniformOutput` flag to false as we will be getting an array of characters for the output for each cell, instead of a single number.  This is **provided** that you have called `num2cell` to convert your numbers into a cell array.

Comment: I have made a change in the formulation, Can you check this out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your edit, you can do this to first convert your numeric array into a cell array of strings like you said:

```
A = num2cell(A);
A = cellfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Once you do this, if my understanding is correct, you want to insert an `A` character before each string.  As such, you can do this:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) ['A' x], A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You would thus get:

```
A = 

 'A2014'
 'A20'
 'A2012'
 'A32144'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be

```
formatSpec = 'A%d';
B = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(A(:), formatSpec)));
B = reshape(B, size(A));
```

- [`strtrim` reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html)
- [`cellstr` reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html)
- [`num2str` reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)

Note that you can modify the format of the resulting strings by changing the `'A%d'` format specifier to something else. Read the documentation of `num2str` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Like @rayryeng said this works :

```
A = num2cell(A);
A = cellfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: Can you please see the formulation again?, Thanks.