# Employing conditions in cellfun MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The questions is:

A=[9 10];

And I want to obtain B={'09','10'};

I made this:

```
    for hij=1:size(A,1)
        if A{hij}<9
            B{hij}=strcat('0',num2str(A{hij}),'');
        else
            B{hij}=strcat('',num2str(A{hij}),'');
        end
    end
```

But I was wondering if there is any posibility to make that without using a loop, maybe using a "**cellfun**"; thanks!

Comment: This is the same question as the one you asked before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084641/convert-string-to-num-with-cellfun/

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
>> B = num2str(A(:),'%02d'); %// second argument to num2str is format spec
B =
    09
    10
```

This gives a string matrix `B`. To convert `B` into a cell array of strings:

```
>> B = mat2cell(B,ones(1,size(B,1))).';
B = 
    '09'    '10'
```

or, as noted by Divakar,

```
>> B = cellstr(B).';
B = 
    '09'    '10'
```

Comment: +1 and for the second step you can use `cellstr` I believe that makes it one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Luis answer is good. Just for completeness, you can use [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) if you really want:

```
C = arrayfun(@num2str, A,'UniformOutput', 0 );
```

Comment: With `f=@(x) num2str(x, '%02d'); C = arrayfun(@f, A,'UniformOutput', 0 );` to get the format in there.